# Tiles on underfloor heating

Tags: heating, heat-pump, ceramic-tile, vinyl-flooring, resistance

I am newbie here but been reading a lot of your comments through this website and thought to finally ask my question.

I am looking for the right type of tile to go on top of my underfloor heat pump heating (Hitachi Yutaki S). I am leaning towards LVT but needed to know if that would be a wise move and what thermal resistance and thermal conductivity values I should be looking for, be it LVT, Laminate or Cermic Tiles.

Really appreciate your feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: Ceramic (or stone) will have lowest thermal resistance. I don't know the numbers, but plastic or "laminate" (plastic and wood) will have higher thermal resistance. That means the heating loop has to be hotter to deliver the same amount of heat to the house, and depending on the details of your heat pump, that can make it much less efficient, or exceed its ability to deliver heat, or not be much of a problem at all. Please [edit] your question to provide details about that, and perahaps also clean up some of the formatting so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Going for the ceramic tile then